# MDF file vs A connection

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I did not try before to include .MDF file in App-Data, I usually connect to Sql Server 2005 or 2008 DB.  Why I would use the mdf file, and what is the Pros and Cons.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .mdf file in `App_Data` is usually associated with SQL Server Compact editions. In production you would prefer to use the full blown version of SQL Server. The local database is good enough for development and testing purposes.